# how to create slide show with html and css only

Tags: html, css

I want to create slide show to display any images to limited space.
And I don't want to use javascript.
How to create slide show with html and css only?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this slideshow](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/slide_show) example using HTML and CSS.

To make it not use javascript, you could just replace the mouseover for each Set (the tabs at the top) with HTML links...

```
<A HREF="section2.html" TARGET="content" TITLE="Slideshow slide 2">Section 2</A>
```

However, it really is easier to use javascript, and almost all browsers will have no problem with javascript. Is there a particular reason not to use it?

Comment: Thank you for answer. That's it. 
Because user can be javascript off. I worry about it.
And also I interest in how to create html and css only.

Comment: fair enough about wanting to create only html and css, but you'll see from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp
That 95% of browsers 2 years ago had javascript on, and that number was increasing.  And generally those who are savvy enough to switch it off will realise a page may not work as a result.  Still, up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a nice pages with HTML/CSS to show what you need and make a redirection between them with HTTP META refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://...">
```

This way visitors would not need to click on links to navigate between pages, but would be automatically taken there after certain amount of time...

Comment: That's good idea, but I want to know the way that user can switch images.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
<a href="3.html"><img src="2.jpeg" alt="..."></a>
```

and so on.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, he is asking for css/html slide show and you gave him a hyperlink. how this thing help?

Comment: See an image. Click, see next image. Click, see next image. etc.